# Найти простые числа в указанном диапазоне

Tags: python, математика, простые-числа

с выводом количества найденных простых чисел

```
a = int(input("Нижний диапазон: "))
n = int(input("Верхний диапазон: "))

print ("Простые числа: ")
      for i in range(a, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, i + 1):
            if i % j == 0:
               c += 1

print("Найдено простых чисел: ", c)
```

Comment: почему вы решили, что где-то есть ошибка? Это к тому, что в вопросе нужно сразу указывать что вы хотите получить и что у вам выдает программа. А так ошибок тут несколько. Сначала продумайте алгоритм, а потом уже переносите его в код.

Comment: Консилиум? Это консоль так теперь называется?

Comment: консилиум - это совещание ученых. Если вы определение простого числа читали так же,как слово "консоль", то неудивительно, что у вас получается непонятно что. В ваших условиях, кстати, не сказано, что выводить нужно сами числа, сказано, что нужно вывести их количество.

Comment: А по сути: 1) почините отступы, в питоне это важно 2) переменные нужно инициализировать, нельзя добавлять что-то к неизвестно чему 3) над логикой определения простоты числа нужно ещё подумать. А вообще вам же выводится ошибка? Читаете её, думаете, исправляете. Опять запускаете. Выводится новая ошибка. Думаете. И т.д.

Comment: ))"консоль" . уже полностью в решении.. спасибо за советы.

Comment: Не нужно портить вопрос. Если вам помог какой-либо ответ - примите его зеленой галочкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for j in range(1, i + 1):
```

вы стабильно делите на 1, а на 1 делится любое число, поэтому вы получаете неверный ответ

вы стабильно делите `i` на `i`, поэтому и тут получаете неверный ответ (увеличение счетчика):

в вашем коде надо так:

```
for j in range(2, i):
```

дальше вы по сути считаете ДЕЛИТЕЛИ, а не определяете простое число, вам надо делать так:

```
isPrime = True
for j in range(2, i):
    if i % j == 0:
       isPrime = False
       break
if isPrime:
    c += 1
```

или сделать от обратного

```
for j in range(2, i):
    if i % j == 0:
       с += 1
       break

...

res = (n - a) - c
```

**P.S.**

если говорить про оптимизацию кода без использования внешних библиотек, то не надо проверять делимость анализируемого числа `i` на все числа от 2 до `i - 1`, надо проверить лишь от `2` до `ceil(sqrt(i))`:

```
for j in range(2, int(i**.5) + 1):
```

правда тут надо отдельно обработать ситуацию для `i = 2`, потому что при таком подходе не будет произведено ни одного подсчета

Answer (score 1):

вот

```
from sympy import *
a = int(input("Нижний диапазон: "))
n = int(input("Верхний диапазон: "))
res = [i for i in range(a, n) if isprime(i)]
print(len(res))
```

Comment: `import *` - не делайте так. Ну, кроме случаев, когда вам реально нужны все 100500 сущностей из пакета. В общем случае засорять лишними переменными среду исполнения - это плохо. Импортируйте только конкретно то, что вы используете в коде.